# Mac OS X: growlnotify doesn't work when script is run from Quicksilver

Tags: macos, mac, bash, growl, quicksilver

Say I run the following script that includes [`growlnotify`](http://growl.info/documentation/growlnotify.php).

```
#! /bin/bash

# do something ...

echo 'I want growlnotify to say this' | \
growlnotify -a '[Some Application]' 'Growl Headline'; \

exit;
```

If the script is run from Terminal or `chmod +x`'d and double-clicked, then `growlnotify` works. If it is run from [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28software%29) instead, then the script works, but it doesn't say anything to Growl.

How can it be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect growlnotify is not in the PATH when run from quicksilver.

In a Terminal, run `which growlnotify`.  It will tell you where the executable is located.  (For me, it returns "/usr/local/bin/growlnotify").  Then, use the full path in your script, and it will always work, regardless of what is in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do the following to get reliable growl notifications

```
growlnotify -H localhost -m "message"
```